# How do I check if an IndexedDB database exists?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I keep it in **IndexedDB** to avoid get device images all the time. I want to check if a db exists. My code is below but this code is not working in Firefox.

My method:

```
const indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

export const isDatabaseExists = async dbName => {
  const isExistDB = (await indexedDB.databases()).map(db => db.name).includes(dbName)

  return !!isExistDB
}
```

Usage:

```
const isChrome = browser.getBrowserName().toLowerCase().includes("chrome");
        if (isChrome) {
            isDatabaseExists("database").then(dbExists => {
                if (dbExists) {
                    getFromDBImages((images) => {
                        this.setState({deviceImages: images, loadingImages: false})
                    })
                } else {
                    this.getDeviceImages()
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.getDeviceImages()
        }
```

This code is nice for Chrome. How can i run this on all browsers? Firefox error is:
[image]

Comment: browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/databases#browser_compatibility

Comment: firefox doesn't support `databases`, another thing, why you return `!!isExistDB`? The method `includes` returns true or false already, there's no need for `!!isExistDB` just return `isExistDB`

Comment: maybe you can simply just open the database?